# Excel - error 28 out stack space

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on some project that contains 276 forms in Excel 2010. What is the purpose of the application: form1 appears, users input something, press next and I validate the user input so I know what is the next form that the user needs to fill. And so goes on, but somewhere in the middle of the whole process I get the error 28: out of stack space.

I have searched the internet, but didn't found any way to solve this, so the user won't be interrupted in the middle of the application.

Basically, what I want is somehow to clear the stack, if it is possible.

**EDIT:**

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click()
    'Getting the column where I need to insert the value from the form
    Dim coll As Integer
    coll = findColumn("WP10200")

    'Getting the row where I need to insert the value from the form
    Dim row As Integer
    row = ActiveCell.row

    'Getting the user value from the textbox
    Dim val As String
    val = txtValue.Text

    If val >= 1 And val <= 4 Then
        Cells(row, coll).Value = val

        If val = 1 Then
            Unload Me
            WP10215.Show
        Else
            Unload Me
            WP10202.Show
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Not valid input"
    End If

End Sub

Function findColumn(CellVal As String) As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim coll As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A1:JC1")

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        Dim tmp As String
        tmp = cell.Value

        If tmp = CellVal Then
            coll = cell.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    findColumn = coll

End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.txtValue.SetFocus
End Sub
```

This code is almost same in all forms (with some exceptions, i.e. different input, displaying some other form and so on)

WP10200 - is the id of the question the user needs to input something. WP10215 and WP10202 too, they are forms like this one with some logic inside.

**Some additional info**, all of these forms are in one macro that the user can start, and than it fills the forms as they show up.

Comment: You cannot clear the stack without also disrupting the current worflow - rather than clear the stack you need to locate and remove the cause of the problem.

Comment: I really can not find where is the problem. Everything is working good except that it fills up the stack. Check my edited post, if you can think of any solution how to fix this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you don't close out procedures. I.e. you have `Macro 1` that calls `Macro 2` which calls `Macro 3`, and on and on without closing any of them down.

You can check which procedures are running, by doing the following:

While running your code in step mode, go to `View` > `Call Stack` (or just press `Ctrl` + `l`).

To fix this, you'll need to compartmentalize the various procedures.

I may be able to give a better answer if you posted some of your code.

--Update--

Your code per form is fine. The issue, I suspect, lies is your *one macro that the user can start* that isn't closing out subs as needed.

As I mentioned before, run your code, then when you get the error, check the call stack to see what procedures aren't being closed properly. You'll then need to change the procedure workflow (Thanks @Tim Williams) to fix the problem.

Given the size of the problem (276 forms) this isn't likely going to be something that will be easily fixed here.

Comment: I will post some of the code, but that code will mostly be repeating in almost every form. Will edit now, so you can check it.

Comment: Updated my question, please check it.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I will try to check all of them tonight, and see what can I do. Will let you know if I find the error.